# ASP.NET MVC Form Submission. Cookie, Static Class Variable or GET/POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been working on it for a while and still can't figure out what to use. Basically, I have a situation where a manager has to assign some customers to the employees working for the business. The basic navigation structure is :

1. Click the desired employees from a list of Employees {need to hold
   the employee ID}
2. Click the desired customer from a list of Customers {need to hold
   the Customer ID}
3. Redirect to the page where Employee ID and Customer ID will be
   available so that it can be written in the database.

I have problem holding the Employee ID till I reach the 3rd step. I tried cookies and declaring static controller class variable to hold employee ID but later I came to know that all the windows share the same cookie which will obviously create trouble. I strongly believe GET/POST should work somehow like this.

1. ShowCustomerList/?EmployeeID=1
2. SubmitAssign/?EmployeeID=1&CustomerID=2

But Im not sure if GET/POST works because the end user have to move back and forth with the pages which might, i think , lose the submitted values. I can explain more if the question is unclear.

What would be a good approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `the end user have to move back and forth with the pages`? Do you have different pages for selecting the Employees and Clients?

Comment: I mean the admin might move back and forth. Like he might select an employee but later might not wanna assign him customers and click back button on browser. And yes, I have different pages for selecting employees and clients, they're different Actions of the same controller.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't feel right for me. Why would you move back and forth between two important (and consecutive) steps? Anyway, there are at least two possibilities: create a single page with two modal windows for searching the employee and the client or a single page with two partial views. Again, this "selection" should be simple and happen in the same webpage or at least in consecutive pages without the possibility to stroll around and do a bunch of other stuff in between. If you really need to store something for later use, store it like `HttpContext.Current.Application["Employee"]= empID;`

Comment: I will try creating View models. Thank you for your thought. :)